# how to use php postgres connection class

Tags: php, postgresql, connection, upgrade

I have upgraded an application to the newest stable version of PHP (8.1) and have noticed an error relating to how the postgres connections are made. I can see in the [documentation for `pg_connect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php), that connection strings are no longer supported in 8.1 and that connection classes are the only way forward. However, I find the [documentation for the new connection class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pgsql-connection.php) a little lacking and I am struggling to find a fully fleshed out example of how to replace it with a connection class instead.

This is the connection string I have now: `pg_connect("host=$dbHost port=$dbPort dbname=$dbName user=$dbUser password=$dbPass sslmode=$cleanSSLMode")`

Would the new connection class look something like this?

```
> final class Connection{
>     private $dbHost;
>     private $dbPort;
>     private $dbName;
>     private $dbUser;
>     private $dbPass;
>     private $cleanSSLMode;
> 
>     $this->$dbHost = pg_connect(host=$dbHost port=$dbPort dbname=$dbName user=$dbUser password=$dbPass sslmode=$cleanSSLMode) or die('Unable to connect to PostgreSQL')
> }
```

Comment: I think you have misread the docs. It looks like the single connection string is fine and it is separate parameters that have been deprecated. The pg_connect function then returns a Connection object.

Comment: @RichardHuxton, that's entirely possible. I got this error in my code that lead me to the conclusion that I had to remake the connection string into a connection class:
`Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: pg_free_result(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type PgSql\Result, bool given`

Comment: You would call `pg_free_result()` on a result obtained from `pg_query` or `pg_execute` or similar, not `pg_connect` I don't think. If it is complaining about a bool, then they returned false and you probably didn't check for that

Comment: @RichardHuxton, you were right, my query was returning false. Not sure how to handle this situation, should I delete the question? Change it? Do you want to post an answer so you can get credit for it?

Comment: If you think the question might help someone else leave it up. Otherwise feel free to delete it